# Get ul width with floating li's using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have this

```
<ul>
  <li>Questions</li>
  <li>Tags</li>
  <li>Users</li>
</ul>

ul { list-style: none }
li { float: left }
```

Basically, just like the menu above ("Questions Tags Users..." on the right of the Stackoverflow logo)

How do I get the actual width of the `ul`?

The purpose is so that I can align this `ul` to the right or centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using `width()` will work in this case.

I assume though, given the nature of your question, you have applied `display: inline` to the `ul` so it's width cannot be read by the DOM.

In this case you can loop through the `li` elements and sum their widths like this:

```
var ulWidth = 0;
$("li").each(function() {
    ulWidth = ulWidth + $(this).width()
});
alert(ulWidth);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vejh/)

To mimic a centered list you would need to find the width of both the UL and collective LI tags.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var w = 0;
        $('ul > li').each(function(){ w+= $(this).width(); });
        $('ul > li:first').css({'margin-left': ($('ul').width()-w)/2+'px'});
      });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      ul,li { margin:0; padding:0; }
      ul { list-style: none }
      li { float: left; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Questions</li>
      <li>Tags</li>
      <li>Users</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! outerWidth() will get the margin as well

Answer (score 0):

Well, try with jquery:

```
var width = $('ul').attr( 'width );
```

you could assign it a value like :

```
$('ul').attr( 'width' , value );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$("ul").width()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery **[.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)** to get the width of your `ul` element

```
$('ul').width();
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aNJk9/)**